# Why does HTTP headers doesn't get created when I use Server.Transfer()?

Tags: asp.net, caching, http-headers, webserver, server.transfer

I'm using an .aspx page to serve an image file from the file system according to the given parameters.

```
Server.Transfer(imageFilePath);
```

When this code runs, the image is served, but no *Last-Modified* HTTP Header is created.
as opposed to that same file, being called directly from the URL on the same Server.

Therefor the browser doesn't issue an *If-Modified-Since* and doesn't cache the response.

Is there a way to make the server create the HTTP Headers like normally does with a direct request of a file (image in that case) or do I have to manually create the headers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Response Header before Server.Transfer in Asp.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417355/how-to-set-response-header-before-server-transfer-in-asp-net)

Comment: @Cthulhu I'm not asking **How** to set the Response Header, rather, **If** I have to set them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand on @Guffa's answer and share my chosen solution.

When calling the `Server.Transfer` method, the .NET engine treats it like an `.aspx` page, so It doesn't add the appropriate HTTP Headers needed (e.g. for caching) when serving a static file.

There are three options

- Using `Response.Redirect`, so the browser makes the appropriate request
- Setting the headers needed and using `Request.BinaryWrite` to serve the content
- Setting the headers needed and calling `Server.Transfer`

I choose the third option, here is my code:

```
        try
        {
            DateTime fileLastModified = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(MapPath(fileVirtualPath));
            fileLastModified = new DateTime(fileLastModified.Year, fileLastModified.Month, fileLastModified.Day, fileLastModified.Hour, fileLastModified.Minute, fileLastModified.Second);
            if (Request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"] != null)
            {
                DateTime modifiedSince = DateTime.Parse(Request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"]);

                if (modifiedSince.ToUniversalTime() >= fileLastModified)
                {
                    Response.StatusCode = 304;
                    Response.StatusDescription = "Not Modified";
                    return;
                }
            }
            Response.AddHeader("Last-Modified", fileLastModified.ToString("R"));
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            Response.StatusDescription = "Not found";
            return;
        }
        Server.Transfer(fileVirtualPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you make a transfer to the file, the server will return the same headers as it does for an `.aspx` file, because it's basically executed by the .NET engine.

You basically have two options:

- Make a redirect to the file instead, so that the browser makes the request for it.
- Set the headers you want, and use `Request.BinaryWrite` (or smiiliar) to send the file data back in the response.

Comment: The thing I'm still missing is how come the .NET engine does not return the same headers in my case as it's basically should.

Comment: @Abir: If you make a transfer, it will handle it as a page rather than a static file, and return headers that keeps the browser from caching it, as you don't want pages to be cached.