# How to use output caching when using Server.Transfer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outputcache

I am using `global.asax` to rewrite URLs which used `Server.Transfer` method.

In the actual page I transfer to, I have `<%@ OutputCache Duration="600" VaryByParam="id"  %>` but the page is not getting cached.

Comment: Here is some workaround: http://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/92-aspnet-mixing-outputcache-with-servertransfer/

Comment: There seems no direct solution to the problem, but the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11417355/79485) may get you some insight.